# Mechanical-electrical analogies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, models

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies):

In the impedance analogy, for instance, this results in force and velocity being analogous to voltage and current respectively.

claim: current is analogous to force

logic:
the unit of impulse or momentum is the Newton-second. current is impulses/second.  Newton-second/second = newton.

I think this might mean that charge is analogous to distance.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia article in full? Read the section "Classes of Analogy". Compare the tables in each sub-section. Force can be analogous to voltage or current depending on the type of analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the mechanical-to-electrical analogies:

mechanical inertia is analogous to electrical inductance.

mechanical compliance is analogous to electrical capacitance.

mechanical force or torque is analogous to electrical voltage.

mechanical velocity or RPM is analogous to electrical current.

mechanical friction (linear) is analogous to electrical resistance.